# failed to restart after installation

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install a 64 bits ubuntu desktop 12.10 to my new asus g75vw from a dvd.
Everything worked slowly but fine until it finished, then the installation program prompted me to restart.I clicked restart button after which the computer freezes and finally I have to power it off. Now I can only boot into windows 7 not grub. Where did I go wrong and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do another re-install? That should fix it. And are you dual booting or was a a full on install?

Comment: I am trying to dualboot ubuntu 12.10 64bits with windows 8 64bits. Since the installation is not bootable I cant reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Although I didn't know why.
But i think it doesn't matter too much.

After the screen freeze when i click the restart button.
I power the computer off.
I went into the Windows 7 OS, AND add the ubuntu entry through easybcd.

Then I restart the computer, and select the ubuntu. 
Everything just goes fine. and I can get into both windows 7 and ubuntu systems based on my selection.

Hope that would help.